# Small Category: Definition

Tags: category-theory

*Reference: Adamek, Herrlich & Strecker, Remark 3.45 and Exercise 3M*

> Given a category whose objects form a set.
>   Then do the morphisms form a set, too?

A stumbled over the construction:
$$\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{C})=\bigcup_{X,Y\in\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})}\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$$
But a priori it involves classes, or?

**Edit**

> Are there counterexamples?

Comment: Aren't Hom-sets always sets? In $2$-categories it's a different story though but normally it's part of the definition right? In that case you're taking a union over a set, so it's ok.

Comment: @Mathematician42 No, hom-sets being actual sets is the definition of a _locally small_ category.

Comment: No, not in a general. Locally small categories are by definition those where Hom-sets are actually sets.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's part of the definition of a category by Adamek Herrlich & Strecker. So are there counterexamples excluding this from their definition?

Comment: I should complain to Rotman (it's defined with actual sets in his book as well). If you don not assume locally smallness, I see no reason why it should be a set. But I cannot cook up an example immediately.

Comment: I think in his treatment it was on purpose since the goal is to work in abelian categories.. But yeah it can be very misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $R$ be any nontrivial commutative ring. Consider the one-object category $C$ with one object $O$ and let $\operatorname{Hom}_C(O,O)$ be isomorphism classes of modules over $R$ and let the composition be the tensor product. Note that this is well defined as $M \cong M'$ and $N \cong N'$ implies $M \otimes_R N \cong M' \otimes_R N'$. As tensor products are associative up to isomorphism and $R \otimes_R M \cong M \otimes_R R \cong M$ for all modules $M$, this is indeed a category. (It's a non-small "monoid"). It should be obvious that $\operatorname{Hom}_C(O,O)$ cannot be a set, as for any cardinal number $\kappa$ there is the isomorphism class of free modules of rank $\kappa$.

Comment: Great answer - thanks a lot!!!